# How to calculate the bottom offset of a modal view on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

When a user taps a UITextField, the keyboard will come up. I scroll up the UITextField to sit just above the keyboard. This is working fine on iPhone:

[image]

```
- (void) someWhere
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(onKeyboardShow:)
        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
        object:nil];
}

- (void) onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] 
        objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue
    ];

    if (keyboardRect.size.height >= IPAD_KEYBOARD_PORTRAIT_HEIGHT) {
        self.containerView.y = self.containerView.y - keyboardRect.size.width;
    } else {
        self.containerView.y = self.containerView.y - keyboardRect.size.height;        
    }
}
```

However, it is broken on iPad. On iPad, modal view controllers can be presented as a sheet that takes up only a portion of the screen. You can see that there is a gap between the last UITextField and the keyboard on iPad.

[image]

```
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:someRootViewController];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need to detect the offset of the modal view from the bottom of the screen and add that to the Y coordinate of the UITextField. This will make the UITextField flush with the top of the keyboard. Through some reverse engineering, I got the frame of the modal view by traversing undocumented view hierarchy:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // describe is a category function on UIView that prints out the frame
    [self.viewController.view.superview.superview.superview.superview describe];
}
```

> x: 114.000000,
>   y: 192.000000,
>   w: 540.000000,
>   h: 620.000000

Finally, to get the offset of the modal view from the bottom of the screen, I do:

```
UIView* modalView = self.viewController.view.superview.superview.superview.superview;
// usage of self-explanatory UIView category methods
CGFloat bottomOffset = modalView.superview.height - (modalView.y + modalView.height);
```

To my chagrin, this only works in portrait mode. For some reason, the modal view's superview is always stuck with a width of 768 and height of 1024 no matter what orientation the iPad is in. So here is where I'm asking for help. How do I reliably get the offset of the modal view from the bottom of the screen, irregardless of the orientation, on iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Use an [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) to attach the text field to the keyboard automatically.
2. Convert the keyboard rect to the superview of the containerView you're trying to move. You can then get its top Y value *in the coordinates of the containerView's superview*.

Something like:

```
CGRect rectInWindowCoordinates = [self.containerView.window convertRect:keyboardRect fromWindow:nil];
CGRect rectCoveredByKeyboard = [self.containerView.superview convertRect:rectInWindowCoordinates fromView:nil];
CGFloat top = CGRectGetMinY(rectCoveredByKeyboard);
self.containerView.y = top - self.containerView.frame.size.height;
```

Comment: Before I spend time implementing `inputAccessoryView`, I would like to know if iPad's Messages App's text input box also uses `inputAccessoryView`. That design is nearly identical to what I have. Basically, the `UITextField` and `inputAccessoryView` are one and the same. The `UITextField` initially sits on the bottom of the screen and animates upward to become to `inputAccessoryView` when the keyboard arises.

Comment: I would guess that it's not using ```inputAccessoryView``` as it has special scrolling behavior with the keyboard. If you want something nearly identical to the Messages interface, you could probably [find one on Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=messages) to use or look at as an example.

Comment: I am attempting to implement your second option, however I am using `UIView convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView*)view`. I convert the top point of the keyboard in `UIWindow` into my text field's coordinate system. This is working fine in portrait mode, but still broken in landscape. When the keyboard comes up in landscape, it pushes the modal view even higher to the top of the screen. So initially, I can place my text field flush with the keyboard, but once the modal view slides even higher, the keyboard covers the text field.

Comment: Ah, right! I forgot about that. I've updated my answer to include the required window conversion that should solve that issue. (The keyboard rect is in screen coords, not window coords, so you have to convert to window coords first.)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] 
        objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue
    ];    

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    // The keyboard height is only correct when in portrait mode. To get the
    // real height, we make the assumption that keyboards are always wider than
    // they are tall.
    CGFloat keyboardHeight;
    if (keyboardRect.size.width < keyboardRect.size.height) {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.size.width;
    } else {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.size.height;
    }

    CGPoint originOfKeyboardInWindowContext;

    switch (orientation) {
        //
        // (0,0) ___________
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |===========|
        //      |===========|
        //
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            originOfKeyboardInWindowContext = CGPointMake(0.0, [VeetleAppDelegate instance].window.height - keyboardHeight);
            break;
        //
        //       ___________
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |           |
        //      |===========|
        //      |===========| (0,0)
        //
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            originOfKeyboardInWindowContext = CGPointMake(0.0, keyboardHeight);
            break;
        //
        //       _________________
        //      |                 |
        //      |                 |
        //      |                 |
        //      |=================|
        //      |=================|
        // (0,0)
        //
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            originOfKeyboardInWindowContext = CGPointMake(keyboardHeight, 0.0);
            break;
        //
        //       _________________  (0,0)
        //      |                 |
        //      |                 |
        //      |                 |
        //      |=================|
        //      |=================|
        //
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            originOfKeyboardInWindowContext = CGPointMake([VeetleAppDelegate instance].window.width - keyboardHeight, 0.0);
            break;
    }

    CGPoint originOfKeyboardInTextFieldContext = [[VeetleAppDelegate instance].window convertPoint:originOfKeyboardInWindowContext toView:self.containerView.superview];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    self.containerView.y = originOfKeyboardInTextFieldContext.y - self.containerView.height;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```